# Separate Cc email addresses from a string c#

Tags: c#, string, split

Say you have a string of Cc email addresses from an email application like

hello@test.com; hello@test.co.uk; hi@test.com;

How can I separate these into separate strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use string's split function:

```
string cc = "hello@test.com; hello@test.co.uk; hi@test.com;";

string[] emails = cc.Split(';');
foreach (string email in emails)
{
    Console.WriteLine(email);
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

```
emailAddresses.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```